# How can I increment value of Enum?

Tags: apex, enum

When I declare Enum class `public Enum X{A,B,C}` and I have Enum variable `X y` and I need to increment that value, in other languages I could just write `y++` to increment it, that is, to change A to B, B to C, C to A.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following solution

```
public static X inc(X y) {
    return X.values()[Math.mod(y.ordinal()+1, X.values().size())];
}
```